# conservative property $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle$ from bases to roots

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $E$ and $F$ be vector spaces of the same dimensions over $\mathbb{R}$ with inner products $(\cdot,\cdot)_E$ and $(\cdot,\cdot)_F.$ and a reduced root system $\Delta_E\subseteq E$ of $E$ and a root system $\Delta_F\subseteq F,$ where $\Delta_E$ is reduced in the sense that for any $\alpha\in\Delta_E,$ we have $c\alpha\in\Delta_E\Rightarrow c=\pm 1.$ Besides $\Pi\subseteq \Delta_E$ is a given base of $\Delta_E,$ and we define $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle_E:=2\frac{(\alpha,\beta)_E}{(\beta,\beta)_E}$ and $\langle\alpha',\beta'\rangle_F:=2\frac{(\alpha',\beta')_F}{(\beta',\beta')_F}$ for any $\beta\in E$ and $\beta'\in F.$ (This definition is to make the formula of reflection more beautiful I guess.)

Suppose there's an isomorphism $\phi:E=\langle\Delta_E\rangle_\mathbb{R}\to F=\langle\Delta_F\rangle_\mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(\Delta_E)\subseteq\Delta_F$ and for any $\alpha,\beta\in\Pi,$ we have $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle_E=\langle\phi(\alpha),\phi(\beta)\rangle_F$ for any $\alpha,\beta\in\Pi.$ Then a conclusion is that we can have $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle_E=\langle\phi(\alpha),\phi(\beta)\rangle_F$ for any $\alpha,\beta\in\Delta_E.$

I see this propery in the Representation of Compact Lie Groups by T. Bröcker and T.tom Dieck(its proposition 5.2), but it doesn't explain it.

I tried to show $\phi r_\alpha\phi^{-1}=r_{\phi(\alpha)}$ for $\alpha\in\Delta_E,$ which is equivalent to the conclusion above, where $r_\alpha:\gamma\in E\mapsto \gamma-\langle\gamma,\alpha\rangle_E\alpha$ is the reflection with respect to the hyperplane $L_\alpha:=\alpha^{\perp},$ and my attempt is to show $\phi r_\alpha\phi^{-1}(\phi(\alpha)=-\phi(\alpha)$ (obvious) and $\phi r_\alpha\phi^{-1}$ fixes every point in $L_\alpha,$ but I only could show $\phi r_\alpha\phi^{-1}(L_\alpha)=L_\alpha$ by the fact that $r_\alpha$ can be written as $r_{\alpha_1}\cdots r_{\alpha_n}$ for some $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\in\Pi$ and the assumption $\langle\delta,\beta\rangle_E=\langle\phi(\delta),\phi(\beta)\rangle_F$ for any $\delta,\beta\in\Pi.$

Thanks in advance for any opinions and answer!

Comment: Reminds me of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357173/96384), and I will ask the same thing here: Since $\Pi$ is, among other things, a basis of the vector space $E$ (in the plain old sense of linear algebra), does it not follow immediately that $\phi$ preserves the scalar product on all pairs of vectors if it preserves it on $\Pi\times \Pi$? (This seems so easy, probably I'm overlooking something.)

Comment: Because here the inner products are not preserved, but some types of their quotients are.

Comment: I see. Am I correct that what is denoted $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$ here is what is often called $\check \beta(\alpha)$? Then knowledge of these for pairs of simple roots means knowing the Cartan matrix, and that determines the root system. But I assume that comes later in the theory, so the question is: What are we allowed to use at this point?

Comment: Some elementary ideas: 1) $(a,b)=0 \Leftrightarrow \langle a,b\rangle=0$ , so wlog the root systems are irreducible. 2) $\langle a, b\rangle$ is linear in $a$, so at least you get the assertion on $E\times \Pi$. 3) The assertion follows as in my first comment if all roots have the same length. Can we use that in an irreducible root system, there are at most two different root lengths? 4) In the same vein, the most elementary road I can think of is to write down the possible constellations of two roots, from there get it for all roots that are sums and differences of them, and then induce.

Comment: Oh...let me try to work on it! Thanks!!